# How to call startActivityForResult() and onResultActivity() in a separate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

In my android app that produces image effects, when it comes to choose image, there are following two optoins:

1) Choose from gallery

2) Take from your Camera

Following is the code that accomplishes the aforementioned task:

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +  System.currentTimeMillis() + "_ePixels.jpg";
File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);



public void onClick(View clickedView) {

    int clickedViewId = clickedView.getId();

    switch(clickedViewId) {
        case R.id.takeFromCamera:
            Intent imageCaptureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            imageCaptureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent,1888);
            break;
        case R.id.chooseFromGallery:
            Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 1);
            break;
        default:
            // As we have only two buttons, and nothing else can be clicked except the buttons. So no need to put
            // code in the "DEFAULT CASE"
    }
}

// Using one onActivityResult() for both calls and using a switch statement to differentiate what was called for actually!

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 1888:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Success, when user actually took a photo and camera returned back it to us!
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MainOptionsActivity.this,ApplyEffectsActivity.class);
                cameraIntent.putExtra("imageFileUri", imageUri);
                startActivity(cameraIntent);
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                // Failure, Activity couldn't receive the photo captured by the camera
                Toast.makeText(MainOptionsActivity.this, "You didn't capture a photo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Success, Activity received the image from gallery
                Uri imageUriForGallery = intent.getData();
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(MainOptionsActivity.this,ApplyEffectsActivity.class);
                galleryIntent.putExtra("imageFileUri", imageUriForGallery);
                startActivity(galleryIntent);
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Failure, Gallery didn't send an image
                Toast.makeText(MainOptionsActivity.this, "You didn't select an image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

It works pretty much fine. But when I try to load some heavy image or run my app on a phone whose camera is of *high* resolution, android gives me ANR error which is obviously due to heavy work on Main Thread.

Obviously, solution to this problem is to do all the *heavy* work on a separate thread. But How to do it? I'm unable to figure out a solution for it. I ain't asking you how to run the code on a separate thread, but how to run *this* code on a separate thread as it is calling another activity, and gaining result from that activity.

Following is the code for ApplyEffectsActivity:

```
package com.arslanali.epixels;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.arslanali.epixels.imagelibrary.ImageEffectFactory;

public class ApplyEffectsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ImageView sepiaGreenishImage;
ImageView embossImage;
ImageView sharpenImage;
ImageView slightYellowishImage;
ImageView slightBluishImage;
ImageView slightReddishImage;
ImageView slightGreenishImage;
ImageView negativeImage;
ImageView greyScaleImage;
ImageView tintSeventyImage;
ImageView tintThirtyImage;
ImageView snowImage;
ImageView darkImage;
ImageView noiseImage;
ImageView flipImage;
ImageView rotateImage;
ImageView gaussianBlurImage;
ImageView reddishImage;
ImageView bluishImage;
ImageView greenishImage;
ImageView blackFilterImage;
ImageView increasedSepiaImage;
ImageView spiaBluishImage;
ImageView brightImage;
ImageView mirrorImage;


Button nextButton;
Button saveCurrentEditedImageButton;

// For displaying the image after modification
ImageView affectedImageView;

ProgressBar waitingProgressBar;

Bitmap sourceBitmap;
Bitmap modifiedBitmap;

// For sending it to next activity for the sharing purposes
Uri modifiedImgaeUri;

// Since, In beginning, we are dealing with the raw image
Boolean isEdited = false;

EffectNames currentEffectName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apply_effects);
    // Restricting the user to use mobile phone only in portrait mode
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // Grabbing the references of all the images
    sepiaGreenishImage      = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sepiaGreenish);
    embossImage             = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.emboss);
    sharpenImage            = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sharpen);
    slightYellowishImage    = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ligth_yellow);
    slightBluishImage       = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.light_blue);
    slightReddishImage      = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.light_red);
    slightGreenishImage     = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.light_green);
    negativeImage           = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.negative);
    greyScaleImage          = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greyscale);
    tintSeventyImage        = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tint_at_70);
    tintThirtyImage         = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tint_at_30);
    snowImage               = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.snow);
    darkImage               = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.darken);
    noiseImage              = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.noise);
    flipImage               = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flip);
    rotateImage             = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rotate);
    gaussianBlurImage       = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blur);
    reddishImage            = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.reddish);
    bluishImage             = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bluish);
    greenishImage           = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greenish);
    blackFilterImage        = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.black_filter);
    increasedSepiaImage     = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.increased_sepia);
    spiaBluishImage         = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sepia_bluish);
    brightImage             = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.brighten);
    mirrorImage             = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mirror);






    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
    saveCurrentEditedImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveit);

    affectedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.affectedImage);
    waitingProgressBar =  (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    // Since, at the start we are displaying the image. So ProgressBar should be invisible
    waitingProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    saveCurrentEditedImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    sepiaGreenishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    embossImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    sharpenImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    slightYellowishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    slightBluishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    slightReddishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    slightGreenishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    negativeImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    greyScaleImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    tintSeventyImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    tintThirtyImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    snowImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    darkImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    noiseImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    flipImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    rotateImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    gaussianBlurImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    reddishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    bluishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    greenishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    blackFilterImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    increasedSepiaImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    spiaBluishImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    brightImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    mirrorImage.setOnClickListener(this);


    // Grabbing the Uri from the previous calling activity
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("imageFileUri");

    try {
        sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri));
        affectedImageView.setImageBitmap(sourceBitmap);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


// Using a switch statement for all cases and storing the result in "currentEffectName"

@Override
public void onClick(View clickedView) {
    int clickedViewId = clickedView.getId();

    switch(clickedViewId) {
        case R.id.sepiaGreenish:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.SEPIA_GREEN_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector sepia = new ImageAffector();
            sepia.execute(sourceBitmap);
            break;
        case R.id.emboss:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.EMBOSSING_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector emboss = new ImageAffector();
            emboss.execute(sourceBitmap);
            break;
        case R.id.sharpen:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.SHARPEN_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector sharpen = new ImageAffector();
            sharpen.execute(sourceBitmap);
            break;
        case R.id.ligth_yellow:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.LIGHT_YELLOW_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector lightYellow = new ImageAffector();
            lightYellow.execute(sourceBitmap);
            break;
        case R.id.light_blue:
                currentEffectName = EffectNames.SLIGHT_BLUISH_EFFECT;
                ImageAffector lightBlue = new ImageAffector();
                lightBlue.execute(sourceBitmap);
            break;
        case R.id.light_red:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.SLIGHT_REDDISH_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector lightRed = new ImageAffector();
            lightRed.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.light_green:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.SLIGHT_GREENISH_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector lightGreen = new ImageAffector();
            lightGreen.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.negative:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.INVERT_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector negative = new ImageAffector();
            negative.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.greyscale:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.GRAY_SCALE_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector greyScale = new ImageAffector();
            greyScale.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.tint_at_30:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.TINT_AT_30;
            ImageAffector tintAt30 = new ImageAffector();
            tintAt30.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.tint_at_70:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.TINT_AT_70;
            ImageAffector tintAt70 = new ImageAffector();
            tintAt70.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.snow:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.SNOW_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector snowEffect = new ImageAffector();
            snowEffect.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.darken:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.DARKEN_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector darken = new ImageAffector();
            darken.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.noise:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.NOSIY_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector noise = new ImageAffector();
            noise.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.flip:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.FLIPPING_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector flip = new ImageAffector();
            flip.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.rotate:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.ROTATE_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector rotate = new ImageAffector();
            rotate.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.blur:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.BLUR_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector blur = new ImageAffector();
            blur.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.reddish:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.REDDISH_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector reddish = new ImageAffector();
            reddish.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.bluish:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.BLUISH_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector bluish = new ImageAffector();
            bluish.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.greenish:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.GREENISH_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector greenish = new ImageAffector();
            greenish.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.black_filter:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.BLACK_FILTER_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector blackFilter = new ImageAffector();
            blackFilter.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.increased_sepia:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.INCREASED_SEPIA_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector increasedSepia = new ImageAffector();
            increasedSepia.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.sepia_bluish:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.SEPIA_BLUE_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector sepiaBluish = new ImageAffector();
            sepiaBluish.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.brighten:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.BRIGHTENING_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector brighten = new ImageAffector();
            brighten.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.mirror:
            currentEffectName = EffectNames.MIRROR_EFFECT;
            ImageAffector mirror = new ImageAffector();
            mirror.execute(sourceBitmap);
        break;
        case R.id.saveit:
            modifiedImgaeUri = saveEditedImageIntoSDCard(modifiedBitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isEdited = true;
            break;
        case R.id.share:
            // Making sure that user has applied at least one effect. Otherwise it will be useless 
            // to share the unmodified image with the use of app.
            if(!isEdited) {
                // If not modified, enforce the user to first modify and then share!
                Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't apply any effect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            Intent shareActivityIntent = new Intent(ApplyEffectsActivity.this, ShareActivity.class);
            shareActivityIntent.putExtra("modifiedImageUri", modifiedImgaeUri);
            startActivity(shareActivityIntent);
        break;
    }
}

public static Uri saveEditedImageIntoSDCard(Bitmap bitmap) {


    // Using PNG format over JPEG for better performance of the app
    String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ePixels_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
    File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
    Uri modifiedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);



    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
        // Writing the image to outStream 


        outStream.flush();
        // Making sure nothing else could be written to file from any other source
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return modifiedImageUri;
}

private class ImageAffector extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Integer, Bitmap>{

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        // Since, image has gone into background for modification. Therefore hiding it and making
        // ProgressBar visible
        waitingProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        affectedImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmap) {
        try{

            switch(currentEffectName) {
                case SEPIA_GREEN_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.applySepiaEffectWithGreenAsMajority(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case EMBOSSING_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.embossAnImage(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case SHARPEN_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.sharpenAnImage(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case MIRROR_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.mirrorAnImage(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case LIGHT_YELLOW_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.produceSlightYellowishEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case SLIGHT_REDDISH_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.produceSlightReddishEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case SLIGHT_GREENISH_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.produceSlightGreenishEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case SLIGHT_BLUISH_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.produceSlightBluishEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case INVERT_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.invertAllPixels(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case GRAY_SCALE_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.turnIntoGrayScale(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case TINT_AT_30:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.tintImage(bitmap[0], 30);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case TINT_AT_70:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.tintImage(bitmap[0], 70);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case SNOW_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.applySnowEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case DARKEN_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.darkenAnImage(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case NOSIY_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.applyNoiseEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case FLIPPING_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.flipAnImage(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case ROTATE_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.rotateAnImage(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case BLUR_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.applyGaussainBlur(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case REDDISH_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.produceReddieshEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case BLUISH_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.produceBluishEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case GREENISH_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.produceGreenishEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case BLACK_FILTER_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.applyBlackFilter(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case INCREASED_SEPIA_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.applyIncreasedSepiaEffect(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case SEPIA_BLUE_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.applySepiaEffectWithBlueAsMajority(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;
                case BRIGHTENING_EFFECT:
                    modifiedBitmap = ImageEffectFactory.brigthenAnImage(bitmap[0]);
                    return modifiedBitmap;



            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            // For the reason: if the size of image is too large to load
            Toast.makeText(ApplyEffectsActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Image","Failed to load image",e);
        }

        return null;
    } 

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap img){
            // After the modification of image, displaying it and hiding ProgressBar.
            waitingProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
            affectedImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            affectedImageView.setImageBitmap(img);
            // Setting it modifiedBitmap so that we could share it on next activity
            modifiedBitmap = img;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params){
         super.onProgressUpdate(params);
    }

    protected void onCancelled(){
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you get ANR? I don't see any code there which could cause that. Isn't the bad code in `ApplyEffectsActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` to do the heavy work in your `ApplyEffectsActivity`. It is all explained on [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Basically, do the processing in the `doInBackground` method and all the UI update in the `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` functions.

In the ApplyEffectsActivity, the flow will be basically:

onStart:

1. show progress indicator
2. start the task

In your task:

1. do the processing in doInBackground
2. hide progress indicator in onPostExecute

---

Edit:

What should be moved to a task:

```
    sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri));
    affectedImageView.setImageBitmap(sourceBitmap);
```

According to me, you should display in the UI a downsized version of the original bitmap (saves memory). Then your tasks would work on that, and on save, you apply the same effects settings to the original bitmap.

Comment: startActivityForResult() and onResultActivity() - Shouldn't these methods be in same **Context** or in same Thread?
`doInBackground()` runs in a thread other than `onPostExecute()` runs in

Comment: Your ANR is occuring when `ApplyEffectsActivity` starts, not when you call `startActivityForResult`. If you want confirmation, paste your code from `ApplyEffectsActivity` in your question.

Comment: I've pasted the whole class. Please check it out and figure out a solution for me. It would be a pleasure!

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! I'll take all these into account. By the way, I'm new to programming and new to Android. What you say about my code quality? Is it O.k?

Comment: If that answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted (tick mark on the left).